# How to route to two different AWS applications on the same domain with different URLs using Applicaiton Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-elb

I have a web app (Node.js on Elastic Beanstalk) already  serving at `example.com`. I have a WordPress blog that I want to serve at `example.com/blog`.

**I want to setup AWS Load Balancer to route requests at `/blog` to my WordPress server and all other requests at `/` to my web-app. How do I do it using AWS Load Balancer(s)?**

My DNS and both of these servers are on AWS. I don't want to setup a self-managed Nginx/HAProxy reverse proxy. If possible, I want to avoid using CloudFront configuration at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by adding a listener rule to an Application Load Balancer. Listener rules *determine how the load balancer routes requests to the targets in one or more target groups*.

After creating the load balancer, see Listeners >> Add Listener. Add a Rule with a Condition for **Path is** `/blog` then select Action **forward** to send traffic to a separate target group mapped to the Wordpress instances.

For more see the docs for [Listener Rules for Your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I did exactly this. The website is perfectly accessible at `example.com` but I get 504 Gateway timeout on `example.com/blog` . WP server is accessible at it's own Elastic Beanstalk url but not via `example.com/blog`